# Erro in ng serve -o angular v11

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm in a "legacy" project on the Angular 11 version, when I do the command ng server -o I get the following error.

[Erro CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de3zn.png)

When I see the error.

[Erro explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0LqP.png)

Something related to mini-css-extract-plugin . I updated the webpack to the compatible version. And I have the same error.

Any solution?

Comment: have you installed all the dependencies successfully?

Comment: Does other command like ng build work?

Comment: I installed all dependencies. I was using it normally, today I got this error. I've been figuring it out early on. I have no idea what it is, I'm new to Angular